# Filter based on cell color

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to write a macro in Excel.

I have multiple sheets and I want to filter based on the fill color.

How do I write a macro for this?  recorded a MACRO using record Macro button but that is applicable only to one sheet. That's all I have done on my own. How do I apply that MACRO to all sheets ? My code is given below:

```
Sub FILTER_MACRO()
'
' FILTER_MACRO Macro
 '
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$17").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, _
        255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Sub
```

Comment: any code you tried on to solve this ?

Comment: Greetings. I recorded a MACRO using record Macro button but that is applicable only to one sheet. That's all I have done on my own. How do I apply that MACRO to all sheets ?

Comment: @user7144104 Post the code you've recorded/ tried so far

Comment: Don't post your code in the comments section, add it to your question.

Comment: I just posted my code in the question

Comment: Basically you need to look up looping through worksheets.

Comment: Many thanks SJR. How do I loop through worksheets ? I am a beginner. Do you mean that instead of writing Activesheet.range, I should write AllSheets.Range ?

Comment: Just google something like "excel vba loop through worksheets" and then try to adapt that code to your specific question and if you get stuck come back and post the code you've tried. People aren't always willing to do it all for you.

Comment: By fill color do you mean the color of cells ? Or the color where the name of the sheet is ?

Comment: Yes .. By fill color, I mean color of cells

Comment: Will the range be `$A$1:$C$17` for all sheets?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Filter_Macro()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Loop through all sheets in the workbook containing the code (ThisWorkbook).
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'With...End With block.
        '".Range", ".Cells" will refer to wrksht due to this block.
        '".Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)" will find the last row containing data in column C.
        With wrkSht
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter _
                Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

            'Original filter range.
            '.Range("$A$1:$C$17").AutoFilter _
                Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

            'Using last row containing data in column A.
            '.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 3)).AutoFilter _
                Field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

        End With

    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Further reading:
[With....End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)
[For Each...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement)
[Range.End Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.End)

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to tick the answer accepted.